# Captcha is not showing up in php

Tags: php, captcha

I am trying to create a captcha that takes words from a file I've named dictionary.txt and uses GD Library to turn them into captcha images. But something is wrong. I can get my dictionary phrases to show up as session variables but they won't make an image. So it must be the GD Library code. There is a final target file named captcha_validate.php but that's not important right now. I am just trying to get the image to work.

**form_captcha.php**

```
<form class="" action="captcha_validate.php" method="post">
    Captcha Verify:
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" /><br /><br />
    <img src="captcha.php" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**captcha.php**

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    session_regenerate_id();

    $file = file('dictionary.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $length = count($file) - 1;
    $random = rand(0, $length);

    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $file[$random];
    session_write_close();

    function msg($msg) {
        $container = imagecreate(250, 170);
        $black = imagecolorallocate($container, 0, 0, 0);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($container, 255, 255, 255);
        $font = "C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf";
        imagefilledrectangle($container, 0, 0, 250, 170, $black);

        $px = (imagesx($container) / (strlen($msg)/1.15));
        $py = (imagesy($container) / 3.5);

        imagefttext($container, 28, -27, $px, $py, $white, $font, $msg);
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($container, null);
        imagedestroy($container);
    }

    msg($file[$random]);

     ?>
```

Comment: `Imagepng` man page says `NULL is invalid if the quality and filters arguments are not used. `

Comment: I did this and it's still not working.

imagepng($container, null, 0, PNG_NO_FILTER);

Answer (score 0):

Try to test if the font path is set right. I did test yout script and it worked when I set the font path right for my environment.

like:

$font = './SomeFont.ttf';

Comment: Okay so it turns out I was using html in my captcha file and I wasn't supposed to use it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out I was using html in the captcha.php file and I shouldn't have used it in that case. That was the main reason why my code wasn't working. Thanks for trying, anyone who commented or answered.